# WASAPI + windows store app initialization

Tags: c++, audio, microsoft-metro, wasapi

I am trying to write a program which captures your speech applies my effect on the captured audio and play it back immediately. I am writing this app to the windows store in c++. After suffering with MediaCapture I decided to use WASAPI to do that. I am using an example from the msdn to set up [WASAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316756%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). As I expected I ran into a problem very soon. So the problem is with the following two lines:

```
const CLSID CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator = __uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator);
const IID IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator = __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator);
```

The visual studio says that:

```
Error: operand of __uuidof must have a class or enum type for which __declspec(uuid('..')) has been specified.
```

I haven't got any idea what it means. I would appreciate some help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to use __uuidof() a uuid must have been declared for the target. When compiling for Windows 8 Store Apps it seems that MMDeviceEnumerator and IMMDeviceEnumerator don't have any uuid declaration and you should instead use the Windows::Devices::Enumeration namespace to enumerate the devices and then use IActivateAudioInterfaceAsyncOperation to initialize and activate the audio device.

Here is a link to a fully working example that captures pcm data and writes it to a wav-file. It uses the systems' default audio capture device but enumerating the available devices and using any of them instead is a piece of cake. :)

[WASAPI sample for Windows 8](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-Audio-Session-ea894455)