# rendering PCM audio bufferin C++ using Media Foundation/WASAPI for UWP

Tags: c++, audio, uwp, ms-media-foundation, wasapi

It's hard to find anything on the web reliable for audio rendering (there is capture, record and save to file, but rendering to speakers are rare using Media Foundation).
The problem I have is that the tutorial of audio rendering provided by Microsoft are... all for desktop application.
There is one that could be used for UWP as it is using [`WASAPI`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316756(v=vs.85).aspx):

But... the uuid of lines fails on UWP:

```
const CLSID CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator = __uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator);
const IID IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator = __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator);
const IID IID_IAudioClient = __uuidof(IAudioClient);
const IID IID_IAudioRenderClient = __uuidof(IAudioRenderClient);
```

Someone seemed to have the same problem:
[WASAPI + windows store app initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493603/wasapi-windows-store-app-initialization)

> Error: operand of __uuidof must have a class or enum type for which __declspec(uuid('..')) has been specified.

Nobody really answered that as well and even more the link he provides is not reachable (or at least not anymore). I Can't figure out how to activate the output audio device and stream audio to it on Universal Windows Platform.

I am using Media Foundation for a specific scenario and I use a Source Reader to get asynchronously audio decoded PCM samples.

While there are samples that should work on Standalone desktop builds, I can't find anywhere something that is compatible with Universal Windows Platform...

Anyone has done something similar (audio rendering using Media Foundation or WASAPI with C++ for UWP?) or at least got better links that would help me?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: *"this does not work"* is not a problem statement. Please take the [tour], visit the [help], and read [ask] in particular.

Comment: I linked just right below one guy with the error statement...

Comment: Did you check this blog : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mediasdkstuff/

Comment: Yes but nothing that helped me.
Simply, I have a BYTE* buffer containing the audio samples, as simple as that. I want that buffer to be played on speakers... in C++, using Media Foundation, for UWP. (so no desktop only code that do not work for UWP).
As such, I can't use for instance the MFCreateAudioRenderer with a MediaSink since it works only for desktop and not UWP.